# Mackey functor question regarding Greenlees and May

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group.

In their paper [Some Remarks On the Structure of Mackey functors](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEUQFjAE&url=http://www.ams.org/proc/1992-115-01/S0002-9939-1992-1076574-2/S0002-9939-1992-1076574-2.pdf&ei=ZaVSUPP5M4f28wT15IC4DQ&usg=AFQjCNFuJ21qi2OIXYT18tuVtjnzDoxFeg&sig2=PhtFfjAqaoK5ytWaVyeJvw) , Greenlees and May define a functor:

$R: GMod \rightarrow M[G]$  where $GMod$ is the category of finite left $G$-modules and $M[G]$ is the category of $G$ Mackey functors by:

$RV(G/H) = V^H$ where $V^H= \{v\in V| h(v) = v \hspace{.2cm} \forall h\in H\}$
and $V$ is a $G$ module.

Question: In Theorem 12,  why are $coker(\eta)$ and $ker(\eta)$ in $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this question would be ok for MO. You may get better access to experts in this stuff over there.

Answer (score 1):

You should think of the lexicographic ordering on pairs $(j,k)$ as giving an ordering on Mackey functors (called *type*) as well as on the subgroups $H \leq G$ (which I'll also call *type*, even though they don't).  In this language, a Mackey functor has type $(j,k)$ exactly when it vanishes on all subgroups of type less than $(j,k)$, but it doesn't vanish on subgroups of type $(j,k)$.

Now, suppose that $type(M)=(j,k)$.  We have a canonical Mackey functor $R(M(G/H_{j,k}))$ of type $(j,k)$ [see footnote] and with the same value on $G/H_{j,k}$, and this receives a map $\eta$ from $M$ **which is the identity on $G/H_{j,k}$**.  Neither the source nor the target of $\eta$ ever evaluated nontrivially on subgroups of type less than $(j,k)$, and because of the above bolded fact, the kernel and cokernel of $\eta$ also evaluate trivially on $G/H_{j,k}$.  Thus, they have type strictly greater than $(j,k)$, so they are in $\mathscr{A}$ by assumption.

---

footnote: This is where we use the assumption that if $type(H)=(j,k)$, then $type(J)_1<j$ for all $J \lneq H$.